# Can a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^+$ always be written in terms of intervals of the form $[0,a]$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Can a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^+$ always be written in terms of intervals of the form $[0,a]$ ?

Comment: No. The set $(0,1)$ is Borel.

Comment: It depends how general your idea of writing one things in terms of other things is - if you mean "anything I could possibly get by any configuration of countable unions and complements allowing for arbitrary structures of nesting in these operations" then, yeah, sure, that's what Borel sets are (though there's great danger in thinking of it that way, since *arbitrary structures of nesting* in *countably infinite* operations is more permissive than you would intuitively think). If you mean something more practical, then no.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if by "written in terms of" you mean the conventional "generated by." Sets of the form $(-\infty,a]$ generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, so the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^+$, being the trace $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^+$, is generated by sets of the form $[0,a]$. However you do need to allow countably infinite set operations. For example, $(0,1)$ can be expressed as:
$$
(0,1)=[0,1)-\{0\}=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} [0,1-\frac{1}{n}]-\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} [0,\frac{1}{n}]
$$
Allowing only finite operations, you would not be able to construct sets such as the Cantor set, since all your sets would have finitely many endpoints.